# Changing colour of a png image in java

Tags: java, image

i need to change the colour of a car PNG image when it crash to a block, like a kind of filter here's the 2 class

```
public class Sprite {       
        //classe estendibile a tutti gli oggetti

    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int width;
    protected int height;
    protected boolean visible;
    protected Image image;

    public Sprite(int x, int y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        visible = true;
    }

    protected void getImageDimensions() {

        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);
    }

    protected void loadImage(String imageName) {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(imageName);
        image = ii.getImage();
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, 
    height);
    }
    }`
    public class Car extends Sprite {

    public Car(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        loadImage("src/car.png");
        getImageDimensions();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose it depends on the picture. If your picture looks like this

[image]

I suppose that going pixel by pixel and using `image.setRGB(x, y, newColour)` on pixels, that satisfy a condition of `image.getRGB(x, y) == colourToChange` will work. If you want to process a picture like

[image]

you would probably first need to run some recognition algorithm to find out which pixels are actually of the car and which are the background (wheels, shadows, etc.) and then run a filter over those. While this time based on the `RGB` of the original pixel you would need to calculate the new colour so that what was originally dark, remains dark and what was originally light remains light and so on.